# Provided health care services: local offer, provision, supply ...?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to describe the number of health care services are provided by local service providers. Thus, should I call the number of services provided as

Local

1. offer
2. provision
3. supply
4. ... ?

Answer (score 1):

"Provision" and "supply" are usually used in the context physical goods like food. For your study, I would write the number of health care services "offered" or "made available" if using just "provided" is not an option for you.